# 3 arguments for 3 tokens but not enough arguments error

Tags: python, fabric

If I create a user named Talbot on an ubuntu server, I'm able to manually change ownership of this user's directory by running this command as sudo

```
chown talbot:talbot -R /home/talbot
```

I try to do the same thing in the last line of this Fabric python script by doing

```
 sudo("chown %s:%s -R /home/%s" % new_user,new_user, new_user)
```

However, it keeps giving me this error

```
  sudo("chown %s:%s -R /home/%s" % new_user, new_user,new_user)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Can you explain why this error is happening?

```
def user_add(new_user, passwd=False):
    """Add new user"""
    with settings(hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only=True):
        # if is_host_up(env.host):
        if not passwd:
                passwd = generate_passwd()
            if not sudo("useradd -p $(echo '%s' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) %s" % (passwd, new_user)).failed:
                run('echo "{user} ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers'.format(user=new_user))
                if env.host== '107.XX.XX.XXX': 
                    sudo("mkdir /home/%s" % new_user, warn_only=True)
                    sudo("chown %s:%s -R /home/%s" % new_user,new_user, new_user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your arguments for your format string need to be encased in a single tuple. So instead of

```
sudo("chown %s:%s -R /home/%s" % new_user,new_user, new_user)
```

You should use

```
sudo("chown %s:%s -R /home/%s" % (new_user,new_user, new_user))
```